# PHP Logging in Wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, logging

guys.  I'm new to PHP and Wordpress and I've been stuck on this for hours and hours.  I'm basically trying to put some code in "the loop" to output the current Wordpress slug and I don't think FirePHP, the only solution I have up and running, can do that.  My understanding is that the loop comes after http headers are sent and that you have to call FirePHP (fb.php) before the headers are sent--I'm assuming that's correct.  What solution would you guys recommend for a newb like me?  The output can go into a browser, third party app, log file, etc.  I don't care.  I just want the data.  Your suggestions are welcome, thanks.

Comment: Mind giving some examples of what you have tried?  This seems very open ended.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I've tried FirePHP included via PHP.ini prepend_file, which I then call using fb("testing...", FirePHP::LOG); within the loop.  It shows nothing.  When put the same line in a PHP file and call it from the browser address bar, it works fine.  I have also tried using a function like this in "the loop": http://www.tcbarrett.com/2011/09/wordpress-the_slug-get-post-slug-function/#.VGvTS8nN5r9 .  I see no output from that and I honestly don't even know where the output should go!  As you can tell...I'm very new to PHP and web dev in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a post slug, just put:

```
echo $post->post_name;
```

Within the loop. FirePHP doesn't have anything to do with it.